# ember.js "onReady" after layout change

Tags: ember.js

Is there a way to trap an onReady-style event in Ember.JS after the layout has finished changing and all new elements are in the DOM?   I have a datepicker that I'd like to use in my ember.js application that requires that you call

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
```

once all elements that want to use the datepicker are on screen.

In my app, I dynamically create input text elements after the initial render and so I can't just call this at the initial onReady have this executed against the new elements.

Is there a way to hook into this sort of event with Ember.js and call this at that time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the didInsertElement event in your Ember.View ala

```
didInsertElement: function() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
},
```

Comment: This will find all .datepicker elements on the page, which may be OK. If you want to just find the .datepicker elements in this view, use: `this.$('.datepicker').datepicker();`